# Why don't ng-bootstrap components work as a webComponent?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, web-component, ng-bootstrap, angular-cli-v6

My example project is based on the Basic Date Picker Example.

As an Angular app everything works fine. But if I build an angular web component with this code, the following functionalities are not working:

- navigation to next or previous month
- select today button example
- changes of the month/year select box

For example: if I put console.log outputs in the selectToday() button method, the message appears, but the actual day is not highlighted.
Also if I click on a day, the NgbDateStruct' model is not filled.

```
Output: 
Month: 10.2018
Model: empty!?
```

This can be reproduced by downloading:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jejk1u

To build a webComponent you must activate the following code lines:

```
    please activate/uncomment the lines in app.module:
    - the constructor
    - 'entryComponents: ...' instead of 'bootstrap: ...'
```

After that you can build and package the web component and start it on http server with http://localhost:8080

```
//build, package
npm run build && npm run package
// to start the http server 
npm run serve
```

Another example is the calendar component. Again, the navigation does not work if it is implemented as a webComponent. An example of this can be downloaded here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-calendar

download - uncomment app.module lines - build - package - run the webComponent on http server

Answer (score 0):

This is by design, navigating to a month doesn't change the model

if you want to change the model and navigate at the same time you will need this:

```
<ngb-datepicker #dp [(ngModel)]="model" (navigate)="date = $event.next"></ngb-datepicker>    
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary mr-2" (click)="selectToday(dp)">Select Today</button>
```

And in your controller

```
selectToday(dp) {
   this.model = this.calendar.getToday();
   dp.navigateTo();
}
```

Comment: i tried it, but if i generate a web component it does not work that way either. Arrow navigation to next or previous month or chose month or year by select box or Button 'to Feb 2013' everything don't work as web component.